# Detecting Android phones on OSX 10.8.2

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, usb, adt

I'm trying to test an Android app on various devices. I mount the phones on my MacBook that has 10.8.2 on it. It used to be a matter of plug and play, I would plug the phone in and run the app from Ecclipse. Everything was fine.

Not so much lately. When I run the app from Ecclipse it opens the emulator and when I did a "adb devices" the list is blank. I tried this with phones from Samsung, Sony Ericsson and HTC, same result.

I then tried to update the vendor list in "adb_usb.ini" like this:

```
# ANDROID 3RD PARTY USB VENDOR ID LIST -- DO NOT EDIT.
# USE 'android update adb' TO GENERATE.
# 1 USB VENDOR ID PER LINE

# Acer
0x0502
# Amazon Kindle
0x1949
# ASUS
0x0B05

etc.
```

When I restarted the adb server and ran "adb devices" again, I get the following:

```
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
ADB server didn't ACK
```

I don't have any clues on how to troubleshoot this. Any ideas or hints is highly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's get stuck. Kill adb's service via Activity Monitor and than restart Eclipse. If that don't help, try to restart your MacBook, it should help!

Comment: When I search for "adb" in Activity Monitor (with All Processes selected) nothing shows up.

Comment: Than just try to restart your macbook. I can see adb in my activity monitor. I had the same issue yesterday and restarting the macbook fixed the problem.

Comment: I've tried that a few times :) It's weird that I can't see adb, though.

Comment: So i guess some other process is using `localhost:5037`, because as I know that's the default port which adb use.

Answer (score 0):

I use 10.8.2 on my MBP at work and on MBA at home. Everything works smooth. Just plug and play ) Maybe you've installed some software which interfere adb server like antivirus/firewall/some kind of usb related applications. Also check that you use the latest adb version.

Comment: Hmm, I have installed the ADT bundle from the Android Developer page. Could that bundle be broken in some way?

Comment: Who knows? ) I didnt use bundle. I downloaded sdk and eclipse separately. Try to download only SDK and start it's adb server.

Comment: run "adb nodaemon server" it should print some log messages

Comment: @Leonidis "Invalid content in adb_usb.ini. Quitting." Maybe this is some kind of encoding issue? When I delete all the vendor IDs adb works, but I guess I need the IDs there to whitelist my devices? It's a catch 22 :S

Comment: So we found your problem ) I didnt add anything there manually. Try to run abd with empty file.

Comment: and remove empty lines from adb_usb.ini, if you have them.